# Splitting Sqlite database python query results

Tags: python, sqlite

I am using the command below to retrieve a set amount of data from a sqlite database and get one big list of results as expected, whilst also exporting to HTML and text documents. I am wanting to split the tables shown in the documents based on the 'messages.conversation_id' column yet cannot figure out a way to do so. I have tried using groupby functions but it just sorts the big list of results.

Thank you.

```
connect = sqlite3.connect(sqlitedb)
df = pd.read_sql_query("""SELECT messages._id, messages.date, messages.body,    messages.conversation_id, participants_info.number, participants_info.display_name, participants_info._id
    FROM messages
    INNER JOIN participants_info
    ON messages.participant_id = participants_info._id;""", connect)
df.to_html(open('messages.html', 'w'))
base_filename = 'test.txt'
with open(os.path.join(base_filename),'w') as outfile:
    df.to_string(outfile)
print (df)
```

I have shown a screenshot of the results I am given below, i would like to be able to split the table into smaller ones based on the conversation_id column. So I have a different table for each ID.

[image: Evidence]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider looping off a cursor list of distinct *conversation_ids* as @CL suggests, iteratively dumping dataframes into growing .html and .txt files, separated by line breaks. Even use a parameterized query and table aliases in SQL for best practices.

```
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd

conn = sqlite3.connect('/path/to/sqlite/database.db')

cur = conn.cursor()
cur = cur.execute("SELECT DISTINCT m.conversation_id" + \
                    " FROM messages m " + \
                    " INNER JOIN participants_info p" + \
                    "         ON m.participant_id = p._id" + \
                    " WHERE m.conversation_id IS NOT NULL")

query = "SELECT m._id, m.date, m.body, m.conversation_id," + \
          "     p.number, p.display_name, p._id" + \
          " FROM messages m" + \            
          " INNER JOIN participants_info p" + \
          "         ON m.participant_id = p._id" + \
          " WHERE m.conversation_id = ?"

with open('messages.html', 'w') as h, open('test.txt', 'w') as t:
    for convo in cur.fetchall():            
        df = pd.read_sql_query(query, conn, params=convo)

        # HTML WRITE           
        h.write(df.to_html())
        h.write('<br/>')

        # TXT WRITE
        t.write(df.to_string())        
        t.write('\n\n')

cur.close()
conn.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Tell the database to sort by the `conversation_id`. Then handle the data row by row, and start a new table whenever the value changes, i.e., is different from the last one.

If you cannot handle the data row by row, then you need one query per table. This requires that you get a list of all conversation IDs first (`SELECT DISTINCT conversation_id FROM whatever`), and then execute the actual query for each value (`SELECT ... WHERE conversation_id = ?`).